# Move SQL Server DB to cloud and create simple front-end

Tags: sql-server, cloud, azure-sql-database, amazon-rds, cloud-hosting

I have a SQL Server database, and I want to move it into the cloud and create a simple browser-independent UI for it. The details are:

- The database is about 2GB in size. It uses SQL Server 2008, however I am happy using any later version. I have successfully restored and tested the database in more recent versions of SQL Server.
- I considered using Amazon RDS or Microsoft SQL Azure for hosting the database. Obviously I have to upload the database into the cloud, I don't mind whether this is by scripting it or restoring a BAK file, and I don't mind what version of SQL Server is provided in the cloud (as long as it's 2008+)
- The interface to the database is via one stored procedure. Information is sent to the stored procedure using an input parameter, then the SP returns a result set of 1 column and several rows.
- The database is currently hosted on a single computer, and has a simple UI where you type into an entry field and it returns several lines of text. I want to create a similar browser-based interface, eg with an entry field, a submit button to call the stored procedure, and an output area for the SP's response.
- Database connections will use SQL Server authenticated logins, as this is the only type of login available to Amazon RDS. The logins will map to a database user that has **exec** permission on the stored procedure, also the database user will be in the **denydatareader** and **denydatawriter** as a security measure.
- My experience is with SQL Server development, TSQL coding and database security. But beyond basic knowledge of XML / HTML, I'm not familiar with the best way of accessing the database from the cloud.

I welcome anyone's ideas or thoughts, or links to suitable articles if this has been asked before.

Comment: You can follow this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zkap/archive/2012/04/01/moving-an-on-premise-database-from-sql-server-to-sql-azure-using-ssis.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for the late reply. My response below is through the lens of Azure SQL Database. Also please consider [SQL Server in a VM](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-management-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-iaas/) or SQL Server in RDS.

- With the database already being 2GB in size, and I’m sure it will grow, that will slot you into at least a standard database [see [Service Tiers]](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/) on disk usage alone.  Now, depending on your workload, you may need to adjust how many DTUs [see [DTUs]](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-service-tiers/#understanding-dtus) (i.e., database horsepower) your database will need to provide the experience you desire.
- In Azure SQL Database, there are a number of options for migrating to
  the cloud, but restoring a .BAK is not one of them. For all options,
  please see [Migrating a SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/).
- Stored procedures are a supported feature of Azure SQL Database, so
  this part of your application should work as expected.
- Depending on who and where they will be accessing your application,
  you will need to configure your Azure SQL Database firewall
  appropriately [see [Configure Firewall Settings on SQL Database]](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/)
  - SQL Server authentication in the cloud should work no different
  than your on premises version.
- Accessing the database from the cloud will be a matter of using the
  appropriate [connection string](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-connect-query/) and firewall rules referenced above:

  connectionString="Server=tcp:{your_serverName_here}.database.windows.net,1433; Database={your_databaseName_here}; Connection Timeout=30; Encrypt=True; TrustServerCertificate=False;"